# Can someone provide a quick App.config/Web.config tutorial?

Tags: c#, appsettings, application-settings, configurationmanager, webconfigurationmanager

I've used these two configuration files many times before, but I've never taken the time to fully understand how they really work.  As most people do, I understand the basics in how to call `WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key"]` to get config values.

Here are some questions I came up with:

1. What happens when you reference a configuration value within a class library, and the library is part of a bigger solution?  Does the app.config need to be copied to the output directory in order for the variables to be found? (I assume yes)
2. Can you directly use a configuration value from an app.config in another class library?
3. Assuming question 3 is "yes", what happens if there are multiple app.config files from different libraries containing configuration values with the same key?
4. What happens when you reference the web.config, but in a class library?
5. What happens when you reference the app.config, but in a website or web application project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying answer to all of your questions is the same:  Unless you set up something unusual, all assemblies in your project will read from the same configuration file.  In a web app, they will all read from "web.config".  In any other project type, they will read from the starting assembly's config file.

Answer (score 4):

The app/ web.config that is used is the one that starts the process. Easier if I give an example:

- Assume all projects in a solution have an app or web.config.
- A test in project **A** calls code in project **B** that calls a web service in project **C** which calls code in project **D**.

In this case code in project **A** and **B** will use the app.config in project **A**. Code in project **C** and **D** will use the web.config in project **C**.