# How to change Setting file value manually by editing config file

Tags: c#, configuration, localization, application-settings

In my C# project, I have a setting file. When I build the project, I have .config that contains severals config string.

```
<applicationSettings>
 <MyProject.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="SettingKey" serializeAs="String">
    <value>This is setting </value>
  </setting>
 </MyProject.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

I tried to change the value of SettingKey manually but no luck. I think that the value is compiled to binary and put in dll file.

**So what can I do to allow editing  setting value manually?**

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing .NET application settings without recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352465/changing-net-application-settings-without-recompiling)

Answer (score 1):

Wondering why you need it manually?

You can always use code to do so

```
Properties.Settings.Default.myColor = Color.AliceBlue;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755(v=vs.110).aspx

Update:
[Changing .NET application settings without recompiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352465/changing-net-application-settings-without-recompiling)

I suppose you can't do it, as its maintained at exe level.

Comment: For example, I define a flag to turn something on and off with out recompiling. How can I do  that?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to modify? I can see that it is exe level.... so no luck. Back to my question:  I want to define a flag to turn something on and off with out recompiling. How can I do that using which technology?